# How to calculate the minimal and maximal distance between these two objects?

Tags: calculus

Suppose that an object $\mathcal{O}$ travels on the $xy$ plane following a path with respect to the time $t$ of the form $\mathcal{O}(t)=(2\cos(t), 2\sin (t))$ and another object $\tilde{\mathcal{O}}$ at the same time follows the path $\tilde{\mathcal{O}}(t)=(2\cos (t+\delta)+1, \sin(t+\delta))$, $t \in \Bbb R$, where $\delta$ is a real number.  I need to know how to calculate the minimal and maximal distance between these two objects as a function of $\delta$. I aready made a graph of the two paths, but I need to calculate this distance analytically. I calculated 
$$||\mathcal{O}(t)-\tilde{\mathcal{O}}(t)||=\sqrt{9+8[\cos(t)\cos(t+\delta)-\sin(t)\sin(t+\delta)]+4[\cos(t)-\cos(t+\delta)]},$$
but I don't what else to do. Actually, I don't know if this is the correct and/or easiest way to solve this problem. I'd appreciate any ideas to solve this. Thanks in andvance. I leave you the graph of the paths:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all notice that if $f(t)$ is always positive, then finding the maximum and minimum of $\sqrt{f(t)}$ is the same as finding them for $f(x)$. This is obviously your case, where
$$f(t) = \big(1+2\cos(t+\delta)-2\cos(t)\big)^2+\big(\sin(t+\delta)-\sin(t)\big)^2$$
Now find the extrema as usual, by solving
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t) = 0$$
and then checking the second derivative to determine which are maxima and which are minima.